# How to upload file and json data at once in react and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I want to send a file as well as JSON data from a form
This is my react handle submission method.

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('File', selectedFile);


const data = {
  name: 'vasu',
  email: 'vasutiwari@gmail.com',
  role: 'student'
}

formData.append('data', data);

axios.post('http://localhost:8000/users', formData ).then((result) => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
})
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

And this Is my server.js method

```
app.post('/users', upload.single('File') , async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.file , req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
})
```

and this is the output I get

```
{
   fieldname: 'File',
   originalname: '4eec81ebddc991f6ff017e600dbf58ac.png',
   encoding: '7bit',
   mimetype: 'image/png',
   destination: 'avatars',
   filename: 'File-4eec81ebddc991f6ff017e600dbf58ac.png-1620467341921',
   path: 'avatars\\File-4eec81ebddc991f6ff017e600dbf58ac.png-1620467341921',
   size: 426281
 } [Object: null prototype] { data: '[object Object]' }
```

i don't want this `[Object: null prototype] { data: '[object Object]' }` instead i want the JSON object i send i am also using

```
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))
```

I am also using multer for file upload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what mdn says about the `FormData` `append()` method parameter:

*This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File). If none of these are specified the value is converted to a string.*

The default string conversion which applies for javascript objects results in `'[object Object]'` - which explains the result you're seeing.

As per the multer documentation, besides files, their middleware actually seem to expect text content types as inputs, so this is probably for the better. Note the express body parsers do not support `multipart/form-data` content types - which is what is required for file uploads -, so they do not get involved with the parsing at all here.

You should just append each text input one by one to the `formData` object, and each will be available as a property on the `req.body` object:

```
formData.append('name', 'vasu')
formData.append('email', 'vasutiwari@gmail.com')
formData.append('role', 'student')
```

Comment: It works... thank you. But it a good approach to send file and JSON form data in only one endpoint or should I send JSON data first and return key and with that key I send another request to a different endpoint to store file/images information so that I can retrieve it later both the user data (JSON data ) and files

Comment: It depends on what your exact use case and setup is. But there is no issue a priori with sending both data and files to the same endpoint, so I would say it's a perfeclty reasonable approach if it works for you.